# Why is synchronized not working properly?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

Here's my code:

```
private int count = 0;

  public synchronized void increment() {
      count++;
  }

 public void doWork() throws InterruptedException {

    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                increment();
                System.out.println(count+"  "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
            }}});

    Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                increment();
                System.out.println(count+"  "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
            }}});

    t1.start();
    t2.start();
}
```

Here's my output:

```
2  Thread-1
2  Thread-0
3  Thread-1
5  Thread-1
6  Thread-1
4  Thread-0
8  Thread-0
9  Thread-0
7  Thread-1
10  Thread-0
```

My understanding is that `increment`  is `synchronized`. So, it should first `increment` one number and then release the `lock` and then give the `lock` to the thread `t1` or `t2`. So, it should `increment` one number at a time, right?

But why is my code `incrementing` two or three numbers at a time? Am I doing something wrong (I'm a newbie)?

Comment: `increment` is `synchronized`, but `count` isn't. The two statements `increment()` and `System.out.println()` are not atomic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While `count++;` indeed is synchronized `System.out.println(count+"  "+Thread.currentThread().getName());` is not, but it access to `count` variable.

Even if you synchronize access, it won't help you because next scenario will be still possible:

- Thread 1 increment
- Thread 2 increment
- Thread 1 print value `2`
- Thread 2 print value `2`

To fix this issue you need to increment and print in same synchronized section. For example you can put `System.out.println(count+"  "+Thread.currentThread().getName());` into `increment` method.

Comment: Or make `count` volatile.

Comment: @chrylis It will solve first problem, but not second one.

Comment: @chrylis Marking `count` as `volatile` will not prevent thread 2 from incrementing before thread 1 prints.

Answer (score 1):

The `increment` method can be run on the other thread after the `increment` method returns, but before `count` is retrieved for the concatenation

```
count+"  "+Thread.currentThread().getName()
```

You could e.g. fix this by modifying and retrieving `count` in one synchronized block:

```
public synchronized int incrementAndGet() {
    count++;
    return count; // read access synchronized
}
```

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    System.out.println(incrementAndGet()+"  "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
}
```

Or use [the class in the standard library specifically designed for this purpose](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html):

```
private final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);

public void doWork() throws InterruptedException {

    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                System.out.println(counter.incrementAndGet() + "  " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            }
        }
    });

    Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                System.out.println(counter.incrementAndGet() + "  " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            }
        }
    });

    t1.start();
    t2.start();
}
```

Of course this does not necessarily lead the numbers 1 to 10 being printed in order, just that no number is retrieved more than once. The following output could happen:

```
2  Thread-0
3  Thread-0
4  Thread-0
1  Thread-1
5  Thread-0
6  Thread-1
7  Thread-0
8  Thread-1
9  Thread-1
10  Thread-1
```

Comment: @Hemlata Oh, it does work, but you cannot expect the print statements to be synchronized too without doing this explicitly, and you didn't mention such a restriction in the question. (No number occurs more than once, no number is missing, the numbers are printed in ascending order on each thread.) Furthermore using multiple threads in that scenario doesn't make sense...

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong that's why it's not working, as I'm a newbie.

Answer (score 0):

What actually happens is that your Threads are snapshotting (maybe a another word is better here) the *current* value of the variable `count` and display it. You can think of it like there is a blue bucket with the number zero and both `Threads` are getting the same bucket in the same color and number. They now work individually on those buckets.

If you want them to work on the same bucket, you have to make them atomic e.g. with `AtomicInteger` or `volatile` or any other tool from the java concurrent package.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:** Given by fabian. To give a single function `incrementAndGet()`.

**Solution 2:** A `synchronized` block instead of `synchronized` method (if possible):

Complete code would be like:

```
private int count = 0;
private Object dummyObject = new Object();

public void increment() {
    count++;
}

public int getCount() {
    return count;
}

public void doWork() throws InterruptedException {

    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                synchronized (dummyObject) {
                    increment();
                    System.out.println(count + "  " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                }
            }
        }
    });

    Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                synchronized (dummyObject) {
                    increment();
                    System.out.println(count + "  " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                }
            }
        }
    });

    t1.start();
    t2.start();
}
```

Comment: That doesn't help since the value still can be changed between a call of `increment` and a call of `getCount`, since the monitor is aquired twice in that case.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative solution without using `synchronized`.

Since your use case is simple  ( just incrimenting the counter and print the value, [AtomicInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) is better choice.

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class TestCounter{
    private AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);

    public void doWork() throws InterruptedException {

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    System.out.println(""+Thread.currentThread().getName()+":"+count.incrementAndGet());
                }}});

        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    System.out.println(""+Thread.currentThread().getName()+":"+count.incrementAndGet());
                }}});

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
        TestCounter tc = new TestCounter();
        tc.doWork();
    }
}
```

output:

```
Thread-0:1
Thread-0:3
Thread-0:4
Thread-0:5
Thread-0:6
Thread-1:2
Thread-1:7
Thread-1:8
Thread-1:9
Thread-1:10
```

Refer to @fabian answer for why these numbers are nor not printed in sequence.

If you expect the sequence in series of numbers in ascending order from 1-10, Threads are not required.